# What do you call two functions increasing with each other?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, terminology

If we have two functions $f$ and $g$ such that $f(x) ≤ f(y)  \Rightarrow g(x)≤g(y)$, what is the name of this property? And what would both directions be called, i.e. $f(x) ≤ f(y)  \Leftrightarrow g(x)≤g(y)$?

Comment: I presume you meant to include "for all $x$ and $y$"... right?

Comment: There appears to be no special name for this property.

Comment: I believe the shifted function $g(x)=f(x)+a$ satisfies your properties, and also the scaled function $g(x)=f(x)\times a$ where $a>0$.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Yes.

Comment: Might this perhaps be called ... ordinal equivalence?